# Does .await block the current thread?

Tags: rust

To give some context, I have the following snippet in part of my code:

```rust
async {
    self.stream.as_mut().unwrap().send(Message::Close(None)).await;
    let close = self.stream.as_mut().unwrap().next().await;
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
    assert!(self.stream.as_mut().unwrap().next().await.is_none());
    self.stream.as_mut().unwrap().close(None).await;
}
```

(Actually, the `async` block is longer, but for exemplifying I believe this suffices).

Here, `self.stream` is an `Option<WebsocketStream<...>>` which I am trying to close with this code. After sending the close message and receiving the ack, I'd test effectively having close the connection via receiving nothing when asking for a new message. Yet if I don't `sleep` between the ack and the call to `next`, I'd still receive something and the`is_none` assertion fails.

I'd interpret that `await`ing for the ack means that the assertion would only be tested once the `await` has returned. But this failing when the sleeping is not present makes me doubt it is the case. Am I missing something?

I am relatively new to asyncronous code, so the question may be basic, and this is what I understood from the [async book](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/01_getting_started/04_async_await_primer.html). The questions I found on SO seem to refer mostly to `C#` async statements, which I don't know are equivalent to Rust's ones.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `thread::sleep` does, and you [shouldn't use it inside an `async` block](https://blog.hwc.io/posts/rust-futures-threadsleep-and-blocking-calls-inside-async-fn/).

Comment: Thank you @herohtar for the reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` does not block the current thread. It yields to another coroutine on the same thread. `thread::sleep` does block the current thread, which is why you should never use it in async code. Instead, you'd use something like `tokio::time::sleep`, which is async and yields. As the book says:

> Whereas calling a blocking function in a synchronous method would block the whole thread, blocked Futures will yield control of the thread, allowing other Futures to run.

That said, if you need to wait 1 second for your test to pass, you may need to rethink the order of operations in your close. That may be indicating a race condition. I'm not familiar with which crate you're using here to know if this is expected for a unit test.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, much less sleeping may be required, I just settled for a value that let the code run and started to try to figure out what was happening.